# What is a word for a person who trusts (someone else)?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, grammatical-roles

Alfred trusts Bob.

In some contexts — especially legal or financial — we might call Bob a [*trustee*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trustee). Following this vein (and pursuing a notion of generalization) what might we call Alfred? A *truster*?

Bonus question: Is there a name for the thing that Alfred trusts Bob *with*?

In working around this question I came up with a few other somewhat related concepts.

- *guarantor*. What do we call the recipient of the guarantee? The *guaranteed*? (Note the disambiguation required between the person who is being guaranteed something, and the object being guaranteed).
- *contributor*. What do we call the recipient of the contribution?

Are these examples of some broader set of English words (or ideas)?

Comment: What might we call Alfred? In this day and age, I'd go with "an optimist".

Comment: It looks at least in formal legal terminology, the [two parties to a trust](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trust.asp) are the *trustee* and the *trustor*.

Answer (score -1):

The opposite of contributor is contributee. [T]he Contribution will entail the transfer to the Contributee of all the assets . . . ." https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/contributee